# Can I choose which startup partition to load on next boot from within an OS?

Tags: multi-boot

Let's say I'm in a Windows partition and want to boot into a Linux partition without interaction with Grub on startup. Is there a way to specific the boot disk while within one of those operating environments? (Ideally without rewriting the Grub default boot partition, for instance, if I were to power cycle the computer.)

I believe Macs have something like this, where a Boot Camp tray icon lets users boot directly into the other partition without having to hold down keys or select at startup.

Comment: The Mac structure causes the volume to be 'blessed' as startup, so the boot finds it first. It only works on regular OS X & Boot Camp volumes. I'm not sure if a similar structure could be applied to a non-Mac system.

Answer (score 1):

UEFI firmware allows setting of BootNext NVRAM entry - which OS boot entry to select on reboot. This can be set by any OS like Windows/Linux.

On BIOS firmware you can set also BootNext for Windows boot manager. This means that Windows boot manager should be in control of the dual/multi boot which is not usually the case for example when dual-booting Linux and Windows - here normally GRUB is in control of the dual booting.

See [Windows BootNext tool](https://www.boyans.net/bootnext/bootnext.html).